# Why react image file resizer returns undefiend properties of it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use this pack to resize an image that comes from an input.

But I don't understand why it's saying that "Connot read properties of undefined"

this is the create.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import InstructorRoute from "../../../components/routes/InstructorRoute";
import CourseCreateForm from "../../../components/forms/CourseCreateForm";
import {Resizer} from "react-image-file-resizer";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const CourseCreate = () => {
  // state
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: "",
    description: "",
    price: "9.99",
    uploading: false,
    paid: true,
    category: "",
    loading: false,
  });
  const [image, setImage] = useState({});
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState("");
  const [uploadButtonText, setUploadButtonText] = useState("Upload Image");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleImage = (e) => {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    setPreview(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    setUploadButtonText(file.name);
    setValues({ ...values, loading: true });
    // resize
    Resizer.imageFileResizer(file, 720, 500, "JPEG", 100, 0, async (uri) => {
      try {
        let { data } = await axios.post("/api/course/upload-image", {
          image: uri,
        });
        console.log("IMAGE UPLOADED", data);
        // set image in the state
        setImage(data);
        setValues({ ...values, loading: false });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setValues({ ...values, loading: false });
        toast("Image upload failed. Try later.");
      }
    });
  };

  const handleImageRemove = async () => {
    try {
      // console.log(values);
      setValues({ ...values, loading: true });
      const res = await axios.post("/api/course/remove-image", { image });
      setImage({});
      setPreview("");
      setUploadButtonText("Upload Image");
      setValues({ ...values, loading: false });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setValues({ ...values, loading: false });
      toast("Image upload failed. Try later.");
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <InstructorRoute>
      <h1 className="jumbotron text-center square">Create Course</h1>
      <div className="pt-3 pb-3">
        <CourseCreateForm
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
          handleImage={handleImage}
          handleChange={handleChange}
          values={values}
          setValues={setValues}
          preview={preview}
          uploadButtonText={uploadButtonText}
          handleImageRemove={handleImageRemove}
        />
      </div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, null, 4)}</pre>
      <hr />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(image, null, 4)}</pre>
    </InstructorRoute>
  );
};

export default CourseCreate;
```

and this is the course create form:

```
import { Select, Button, Avatar } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const CourseCreateForm = ({
  handleSubmit,
  handleImage,
  handleChange,
  values,
  setValues,
  preview,
  uploadButtonText,
}) => {
  const children = [];
  for (let i = 9.99; i <= 100.99; i++) {
    children.push(<Option key={i.toFixed(2)}>${i.toFixed(2)}</Option>);
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Name"
          value={values.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <textarea
          name="description"
          cols="7"
          rows="7"
          value={values.description}
          className="form-control"
          onChange={handleChange}
        ></textarea>
      </div>

      <div className="form-row">
        <div className="col">
          <div className="form-group">
            <Select
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              size="large"
              value={values.paid}
              onChange={(v) => setValues({ ...values, paid: !values.paid })}
            >
              <Option value={true}>Paid</Option>
              <Option value={false}>Free</Option>
            </Select>
          </div>
        </div>

        {values.paid && (
          <div className="form-group">
            <Select
              defaultValue="$9.99"
              style={{ widht: "100%" }}
              onChange={(v) => setValues({ ...values, price: v })}
              tokenSeparators={[,]}
              size="large"
            >
              {children}
            </Select>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="category"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Category"
          value={values.category}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-row">
        <div className="col">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block text-left">
              {uploadButtonText}

              <input
                type="file"
                name="image"
                onChange={handleImage}
                accept="image/*"
                hidden
              />
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        {preview && (
           
            <Avatar width={200} src={preview}>

            </Avatar>
         
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <Button
            onClick={handleSubmit}
            disabled={values.loading || values.uploading}
            className="btn btn-primary"
            loading={values.loading}
            type="primary"
            size="large"
            shape="round"
          >
            {values.loading ? "Saving..." : "Save & Continue"}
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default CourseCreateForm;
```

and I have this error:

[image]

The version of the react-image-file-resizer is 0.4.7, I used also 0.4.2 and 0.4.8..
npm: '8.19.2',
node: '18.12.1'.

Comment: Lose the squiggly brackets `import Resizer from "react-image-file-resizer";`

Comment: if i do that i got this: react_image_file_resizer__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.imageFileResizer is not a function

Comment: Something else is breaking it then I suspect, it's definitely a default export therefore doesn't need the brackets

Comment: could be. but I don't understand what..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling Resizer.default.imageFileResizer like this:

```
    Resizer.default.imageFileResizer(file, 720, 500, "JPEG", 100, 0, async (uri) => {
  try {
    let { data } = await axios.post("/api/course/upload-image", {
      image: uri,
    });
    console.log("IMAGE UPLOADED", data);
    // set image in the state
    setImage(data);
    setValues({ ...values, loading: false });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    setValues({ ...values, loading: false });
    toast("Image upload failed. Try later.");
  }
});
```

If you console.log(Resizer) the first property in the object is default for some weird reasons.